# How to elegantly collaborate in Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, collaboration, clasp

So I'm on a team of 2-3 developers who will be primarily working with Apps Script connected to Google Sheets.

I've looked into various tools/workflows but there seems to be no elegant way for two people to work on the same Apps Script file at the same time:

- If two people are both editing the same file on the online editor and save their changes, only one set of changes is carried over with the other being overwritten. This makes sense but I was hoping for a Google docs-like experience when multiple editors were working on the same file.
- Developing locally and version controlling with `git` is also not a great option as to iteratively make changes and test those changes requires it to be on the cloud (because of our Google Sheets dependency). You can not make changes locally and test to see the effect of those changes without doing a `clasp push` call each time and then running the code in the native Apps Script GUI on the cloud.
- I've read the Apps Script documentation pretty thoroughly (deployments, versionsing, collaboration, etc.) but nothing stands out as a elegant solution to this problem (seems to summarize "Use a shared Google Drive" and "Use `git`"...).

I'd be curious as to whether anyone has had experience working on a team environment with App Script and what workflows ended up being used. How do teams have 2+ people work on the same file while also allowing rapid iteration without the friction of needing to call `clasp pull/push` every iteration? Or is this unavoidable?

Comment: Test individually and push pr to master github. Pull latest changes and start working again.

Comment: As of Aug 2022, with their "new" project editor, I have experienced silent losses of changes when trying to collaborate with just 1 person. Even though we coordinate to work on it at different times. There seems to be no undo history. I am new to this, and was also disappointed that it isn't Docs-like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, you can't. There are many challenges and security issues. For example, if the script is tied to a trigger owned by an individual and uses certain copes like Gmail/Drive, you do not want to give others edit access to the script cause that will inadvertently give them access to the individuals other Google data (like Gmail/Drive).

The current version of the online editor does not support collaboration like you're describing. There is a new version of the IDE coming but who knows when that will happen and if it'll address this functionality.

You could use `clasp run` to run the code locally but that may not work elegantly with all use-cases. Plus, it still requires you to do `clasp push` first.

You can have multiple folks edit/collaborate but not at the same time. :/ Not that I have seen. It's a huge struggle for me.

Comment: *There is a new version of the IDE coming* Any source?

Comment: What, you don't trust me? I'm hurt. :P Check out https://support.google.com/a/table/7539891 and filter on Apps Script. RE: "New Integrated Development Environment (IDE)"

Comment: ;) Not that I don't trust you, just wanted to know more information. It seems new editor is based on Monaco(vscode)- That's cool :)

Comment: I was teasing. Yea, I can't wait. I use `clasp` with VS Code and it works great but I'd love to have a more robust online editor for times I need to make a quick change/fix.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've asked around in other forums and this seems to be the general sentiment.

Answer (score 0):

Alternativly you can use [Google Apps Script GitHub Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-apps-script-github/lfjcgcmkmjjlieihflfhjopckgpelofo?hl=en) which is a chrome extension.
[image]
[image]